# Как задать правило обнуления выделенных чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript, html

Как задать правило обнуления выделенных чекбоксов в данной ситуации?
На странице реализованы чекбоксы, по которым формируются ссылки.
Когда выделяется 3 чекбокса, выполняется переход по ссылке.

Если после того, как будет выполнен переход по ссылке, нажать в браузере кнопку "назад", чекбоксы будут уже выделены. Как обнулять их при каждой новой загрузке?

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="site.ru/" class="check-example">
<input type="checkbox" value="catalog/" class="check-example">
<input type="checkbox" value="1.html" class="check-example">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обнуление без использования `jquery`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
  [...document.getElementsByClassName('check-example')].forEach(item =>{
    item.checked = false
  })
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="site.ru/" class="check-example">
<input type="checkbox" value="catalog/" class="check-example">
<input type="checkbox" value="1.html" class="check-example">
```

Answer (score 2):

Сбросит флажки при загрузке страницы

```js
$('.check-example').prop('checked', false);
```